# Mpi4py code does not finish completion in one folder, but works fine in another

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing, hpc, mpi4py

I am running a mpi4py code on a hpc cluster. The full package constitutes of a python code and a job submission scipt. When I submit the job submission script, it runs as expected (runs inside the expected amount of time) in the first few attempts. But, after the first few successful runs, when I submit the same job script, it keeps on running for a very long time (finally, I have to delete the job.) In the error file, I see the following message:

```
sh: BASH_FUNC_module(): line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
sh: BASH_FUNC_module(): line 0: `BASH_FUNC_module() () {  eval 
                                `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`'
sh: error importing function definition for `BASH_FUNC_module'
```

Interestingly, when I create a new folder in the cluster, and copy paste the same exact python code and job submission script and then execute the job submission script, it runs fine. I am a little confused here. I am fairly confident that my python script is correct (it runs fine in the newly created folder), but the same exact script keeps on running endlessly in the older folder. Also, in the newer folder, I do not get this error message.

What is the reason for this? And how can I avoid this? I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: have a look at https://kb.brightcomputing.com/faq/index.php?action=artikel&cat=2&id=239&artlang=en long story short, try to `. /etc/profile.d/modules.sh` at the beginning of your job submission script.

Comment: Gilles: Should I add this line `source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
` at the beginning of my job submission script ?

Comment: yes, you should try that first

Comment: Gilles: Thanks, I am trying that. Also, one more thing that I notice is when I logout of the cluster and then log in again, this problem disappears. Presently, I am adding this line `source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh` in my pbs script after the lines `#!/bin/sh` and `#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=16`. I hope that's okay. The script works fine (but also I logged out and then logged in again now). But, I want to test it again in case the problem shows itself again. Many thanks for the help.